# music21 --> stream.chordify() not working

Tags: python, music21

total newbie with music21 here.

I'm trying to use chordify(): http://web.mit.edu/music21/doc/usersGuide/usersGuide_09_chordify.html

How do you obtain a stream object (on which you can call chordify()) from a midi file?

I tried two approaches:

## 1:

```
s = converter.parse(fn)
for el in s.recurse():
    print '\n'
    if 'Stream' in el.classes:
        el.chordify() # NOT WORKING! throws error.
    if 'Score' in el.classes:
        el.chordify() # NOT WORKING EITHER! also throws error.
```

## 2:

```
stream = c.parseFile(fn, format='.mid')
print stream # NOTHING! stream is None
```

Thanks in advance for telling me how I can get that stream object on which to call chordify(), from my midi file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first answer was on the right track. After running

```
s = converter.parse(fn)
```

do

```
s2 = s.chordify()
```

Then you can call s2.show() or whatever you want.

Comment: Yes it was correct with the first approach. It's just that chordify() took something like 20mins to complete, so at first I thought it didn't work, but then I let it run and went away -- and yes it worked fine, just long. phew! The doc doesn't lie -- good :)

Comment: See the recent discussion on the music21list (Google groups) about what's happening in the near future for speedups and some work arounds

Comment: Chordify on some MIDI files is still slow, but it's way faster on XML than before.